# Trouble making a particular sampling schematic diagram using ggplot2 and ggforce

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggforce

I've been trying to make a reproducible version of a diagram of the sampling scheme for a particular field project, mirroring this version that I made by hand in PowerPoint:

Original sampling schematic figure

[image]

Geom_mark_rect from ggforce has been super helpful for creating boxes around the collections of points. However, I've been having trouble making the boxes fit more tightly around the points (and not being forced to squares); when I try to make a similarly narrow version of the R figure, the boxes overlap:

Current R sampling schematic figure

[image]

It would be great if there were a way to make the geom_mark_rect boxes tighter around the points; any advice on parameters to change or things to try would be greatly appreciated. Or, other creative approaches to trying to make this diagram via ggplot would be so helpful!

The code used to produce the current R figure is below, where data_forchart can be imported from the attached .csv:

```
facet.labs =  c("Tide Pool 1\n (S1)", "Tide Pool 2\n (S2)", "Nearshore\n (N)")
names(facet.labs) = c("S1", "S2", "N")

data_forchart$Location= factor(data_forchart$Location, levels=c("S1", "S2", "N"))
data_forchart$chart_num= factor(data_forchart$chart_num, levels=c("3", "2", "1"))


sample_schema = ggplot(data = data_forchart, aes(x = Time, y = chart_num, shape = Location, color = Time, fill = Time)) + 
  geom_beeswarm(cex= 2, size = 3) + 
  geom_mark_rect(expand = .03) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 17, 16)) + 
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE, begin = 0, end = .97, direction = -1) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE, begin = 0, end = .97, direction = -1) +
  facet_grid(Location ~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = "y", labeller = labeller(Location = facet.labs)) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
theme(strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = .9))
```

[data_forchart](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/files/11971114/Chart_Data.csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems quite fiddly getting `geom_mark_rect` to adopt a particular aspect ratio. It would be nice if `geom_rect` had the option to have rounded corners, but it doesn't. You can instead use `geom_box` from `ggh4x`

```r
library(ggforce)
library(ggh4x)
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(data = data_forchart, aes(x = Time, y = chart_num, shape = Location,
                                 color = Time, 
                                 fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0.05)))) + 
  geom_beeswarm(cex = 2, size = 4) + 
  geom_box(aes(xmin = after_stat(x) - 0.45, 
                             xmax = after_stat(x) + 0.45,
                             ymin = after_stat(y) - 0.4, 
                             ymax = after_stat(y) + 0.45),
                         radius = unit(5, "pt")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 17, 16)) + 
  scale_color_viridis_d(direction = -1) +
  facet_grid(Location ~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", 
             switch = "y", labeller = labeller(Location = facet.labs)) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = .9))
```

[image]

Comment: As an exported rounded rectangle geom, I've also made https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/reference/geom_box.html if that is of any use.

Comment: @teunbrand thank you. I was going to change this over, as it would be nicer to use an exported function, but for some reason I can't get the radius parameter to do anything in this particular example, and all the rectangles have corners. I have no idea why. Are you able to run it and see if this is peculiar to my setup? The other examples in the docs work as intended.

Comment: I do recall this being a bug in 0.2.3, but this was fixed in 0.2.4. I can use `geom_box()` as a drop-in replacement for `geom_rrect()`, with corner rounding and all.

Comment: @teunbrand you're right. I was on the previous version. Now updated and working well.